# commons-io-2.4.jar is showing as Native Platform with 0 supported device

Tags: android, jar, google-play, apache-commons

[image]I have developed an APP using apache commons-io-2.4.jar for network data operations now
I want to deploy my APK in Google's Play Store.

I have deployed my app with version 1.0 with commons-io-2.4.jar then it's not showing any supported device and **commons-io-2.4.jar** is showing as **Native Platform**  but when I have removed this commons-io-2.4.jar in 1.3 version its showing me something 9K supported devices.

Now Problem is, I have not define any NDK configuration but this jar file still showing as native Platform.

can Anyone help me to deploy my App with commons-io-2.4.jar at Play Store.

Any help would be appreciated great.

Comment: Did you imported the .jar in your project or you added the dependency in build.gradle?

Comment: i am using dependency compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4' for this.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on this I had the same issue.

All Android devices were incompatible with my app. The message was 'Doesn't support required ABI - commons-io-2.4.jar'

I had to exclude the commons.io from apache in the build.gradle.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        exclude module: 'org.apache.commons.io'
    }
}
```

Then include my own downloaded commons-io 2.6 from [mvnrepo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.6)

```
implementation files('libs/commons-io-2.6.jar')
```

Make sure to add the jar file in libs directory and right click to 'Add as Library'. Hope this helps someone.