# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS when instrumented testing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, abi, android-install-apk

I have troubles with instrumented tests in Android Studio. When I want to run the instrumented tests on an emulator (Nexus 5 API 24, x86) with command `gradlew connectedAndroidTest`, it fails with `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113` error. But I can normally install the app on the emulator, no problem. It fails only during tests. And the tests runs perfectly on a physical device (Samsung Galaxy S8 or Huawei GRA-L09).
As I saw in another thread, I added this in my gradle file, but it didn't solve the problem :

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

I also tried to run a new emulated device with another CPU/API (x86_64 or armeabi-v7a), didn't help.

I'm running Android Studio 3.0.1 with gradle version 4.1

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: No :( I had to give up

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem, for me it was related to following dependancy:

```
androidTestImplementation 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
```

resolved by replacing it by:

```
androidTestImplementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
```

more info here: [commons-io-2.4.jar is showing as Native Platform with 0 supported device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389757/commons-io-2-4-jar-is-showing-as-native-platform-with-0-supported-device)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, I had a version dependency conflict with mockito, updated it and it is solved. My best advice is to look at your androidTestImplementations and look for conflicts with other dependencies.